# How to fix the "Illegal partition" error in hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have written a custom partitioner. When I have number of reduce tasks greater than 1, the job is failing. This is the exception which I'm getting:

```
 java.io.IOException: Illegal partition for weburl_compositeKey@804746b1 (-1)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:930)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$OldOutputCollector.collect(MapTask.java:499)
```

The code which I have written is

```
public int getPartition(weburl_compositeKey key, Text value, int numPartitions)
{
    return (key.hashCode()) % numPartitions;
}
```

This the `key.hashCode()` equals `-719988079` and mod of this value is returning `-1`.

Appreciate your help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The calculated partition number by your custom `Partitioner` has to be non-negative. Try:

```
public int getPartition(weburl_compositeKey key, Text value, int numPartitions)
{
    return (key.hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numPartitions;
}
```

Comment: This question received 3 answers - two correct and one incorrect. Too bad the only incorrect one received the best score and the accepted answer mark.

Comment: @AndrewSkiba thanks for pointing this out. I corrected the answer according to Tanveer's suggestion.

Comment: Glad to see that. GJ!

Answer (score 4):

A warning about using:

```
public int getPartition(weburl_compositeKey key, Text value, int numPartitions)
{
    return Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % numPartitions;
}
```

If you hit the case where the `key.hashCode()` is equal to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` you will still get a negative partition value. It is an oddity of Java, but `Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE)` returns `Integer.MIN_VALUE` ( as in -2147483648). You are safer taking the absolute value of the modulus, as in:

```
public int getPartition(weburl_compositeKey key, Text value, int numPartitions)
{
    return Math.abs(key.hashCode() % numPartitions);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use

```
public int getPartition(weburl_compositeKey key, Text value, int numPartitions)
{
    return (key.hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numPartitions;
}
```